# Snap from .jar file

Tags: snap, ubuntu-core

I am new to snapcraft. When I create a snap from a .jar file it shows `Error: Unable to access jarfile`. I searched a lot, but it didn’t work. Someone gives an example for creating a snapcraft.yaml file. I saw some examples to change the path. I also did that, but again it shows the same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Snap from already compiled jar?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038646/snap-from-already-compiled-jar)

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Please do not create a new question to add details, you can edit it. Now you have two questions and one answer. Don’t both the question describe the same problem? Can the answer be applied to the other question?

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly.

```
grade: stable
confinement: strict
apps:
  test:
    command: usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -jar $SNAP/src/SnapTest.jar
    plugs: [unity7, network, home]
    environment:
      JAVA_HOME: $SNAP/usr/lib/jvm/default-java
      CLASSPATH: $SNAP/jar/SnapTest.jar
      PATH: $SNAP/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin:$PATH
parts:
  test:
  source: .
  plugin: dump
  stage-packages: [openjdk-8-jre, openjdk-8-demo]
```

Comment: It looks like the YAML indentations were mangled when you pasted them into the answer box. I know next to nothing about Snap packaging, so could you please [edit] your post to add the correct indentation? Thanks.

Comment: I fixed the indentation to what I believe is correct.